# How to retrieve value from second level pointer in Parse for iOS using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have following structure in Parse

Class_A

1. objectID
2. b_ID (this is a pointer having value as objectID to B)

Class_B

1. objectID
2. c_ID (this is a pointer having value as objectID to C)
3. someParameterinB

Class_C

1. objectID
2. someParameterinC

I am using following code to retrieve;

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class_A"];
    [query includeKey:@"b_ID"];
    [query includeKey:@"Class_B.c_ID"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded. The first 50 objects are available in object
            self.myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

Now when it comes to display in UITableViewCell, I am using following code:

```
PFObject *aObject = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

PFObject *bObject = [aObject objectForKey:@"b_ID"];

PFObject *cObject = [bObject objectForKey:@"c_ID"];
```

I am getting issue with cObject. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
[query includeKey:@"b_ID"];
[query includeKey:@"Class_B.c_ID"];
```

with

```
[query includeKey:@"b_ID.c_ID"];
```

and the query response will include both `B` and `C` objects.